# Access the real /sdcard

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery

I flash my HTC One with a custom rom, then I access my sd card in my computer all of the files are gone.

But when go to clockworkmod recovery and select install zip on /sdcard
I can see all my files and roms there.

The question is, how can I access my sdcard?

Comment: What do you see if you use a file browser (e.g. [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)) on the device to look at /sdcard?  Also, is this the new One or one of the other devices called "One"?

Comment: The new HTC One, I flash it to 4.3 Google Play Edition.
I have ES File Explorer, I only see the sdcard folder icon with a small arrow icon on the lower left

Comment: The arrow just indicates it's a symlink.  Do you see anything if you open it?  How about if you open `/storage/sdcard0`?